# rbind with different levels of precision

Tags: r

I want to rbind 2 vectors with different levels of preceision

```
r1 = rnorm(100)
r2 = rnorm(100)
rbind(round(quantile(r1),5), round(quantile(r2),2))
```

rbind returns rounding to 5. How can I get it to display the correct rounding? Thank you

Comment: This returns exactly what it is supposed to. What precise result were you expecting?

Comment: Is coercing to a string out of the question?

Comment: user3022875, did either of the answers meet your needs? It is customary on SO to close out a question by "accepting" one of the answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a distinction between how a number is *calculated/stored* and how it is *displayed*.

In the case of *calculation/storing*: when you `round` a number, the number of digits you impose is not being stored with the number. That is, once the `round`ing is complete, nothing can tell that it was rounded, its history is clean. So when you store `round(pi,2)`, you are storing a floating point number that is approximately `3.14`.

Regardless of how many significant digits a number may have, however, I can *display* as many digits as I want. I can print `1e5` with 5 digits and `pi` with 1, the number digits I impose is not limited to what is significant. In your case, you rounded the quartiles to 2 digits, but you can still print them with 5 if you choose.

You rounded some quartiles to 5 digits and some other quartiles to 2 digits, and then lumped them together into one matrix. As far as R is concerned, it is a 2x5 matrix of floating point numbers; there is no knowledge of how many digits they once had or how many digits are significant, just that they are floating point numbers.

It seems like you expect the first row to have 5 digits and the second row to have 2 digits. When R displays/prints a vector, matrix, or data.frame, the digits (as set with `options(digits=22)` for instance) are used for displaying the entire object, not just a row at a time.

What you may be seeking is a specific textual representation of your numbers. I suggest if you want them row-oriented such as your code suggests, you may be better off with:

```
set.seed(2)
r1 = rnorm(100)
r2 = rnorm(100)
mtx = rbind(quantile(r1), quantile(r2)) # with or without rounding
options(digits=6)
mtx
#            0%       25%       50%      75%    100%
# [1,] -2.45171 -0.855833 -0.140224 0.813804 2.09082
# [2,] -2.09923 -0.793072  0.122728 0.751018 2.11007
t(mapply(function(r,n) sprintf(sprintf("%%0.%df", n), r[[1]]),
         apply(mtx, 1, list), # converts mtx to list of rows, hackish
         list(5, 2)           # the num of digits for each row
        ))
#      [,1]       [,2]       [,3]       [,4]      [,5]     
# [1,] "-2.45171" "-0.85583" "-0.14022" "0.81380" "2.09082"
# [2,] "-2.10"    "-0.79"    "0.12"     "0.75"    "2.11"
```

Answer (score 1):

The resulting matrix **displays** rounding to 5 in the second row, but the values for that row are actually rounded to 2. You can see this by examining the second row by itself.

```
set.seed(123)
m1 <- rbind(round(quantile(rnorm(10)), 5), 
            round(quantile(rnorm(10)), 2))

m1
           0%      25%      50%     75%    100%
[1,] -1.26506 -0.53177 -0.07983 0.37801 1.71506
[2,] -1.97000 -0.33000  0.38000 0.65000 1.79000

m1[2, ]
   0%   25%   50%   75%  100% 
-1.97 -0.33  0.38  0.65  1.79
```

So the answer is: if you want to display different levels of rounding per row when examining the matrix in a console - you cannot, but you can be confident that the values are as expected. If you want to format the matrix per row as a different kind of output, *e.g.* a table in a document, that's a different question.